# Get formatted date using entity frame work linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, ado.net-entity-data-model

How can I get the formatted date in entity collection
I am using the below code

```
  var objholiday = context.tblHolidayCalendars.Where(x => x.isDelete == false)
                          .Select(x => new 
                                 { 
                                      x.recordId,
                                      x.date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"),
                                 });
```

It is not working.have any method to work out it

Comment: "Not Working" as in? Formatting issue, any exception you're getting? Be Specific.

Comment: As @Rahul says... *it's not working* - the single most unhelpful phrase you can use.  What isn't working? What is it not doing? What is it doing that it shouldn't be doing? Help us to help you

Comment: Getting error on `x.date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"),` is 
`Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.`

Comment: SQL doesn't recognize `ToString()` use built in date functions of SQL or cast `AsEnumerable()` before `Select()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't easily do date formatting in a `IQueryable` query...

```
  var objholiday = context.tblHolidayCalendars
                      .Where(x => x.isDelete == false)
                      .Select(x => new 
                             { 
                                  x.recordId,
                                  x.date, // Remove HERE
                             })
```

Add

```
 .AsEnumerable()
 .Select(x => new { x.recordId, date = x.date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") };
```

because the SQL Server doesn't know of the `ToString()` method.

So you execute the query returning a date (as `DateTime`), and then locally (`.AsEnumerable()`) you do the transformations you need.

Note that if `date` can be `null` then you have to:

```
 .AsEnumerable()
 .Select(x => new { x.recordId, date = x.date != null ? x.date.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") : null };
```

Note that you **can** format the date SQL side, but it is a little more complex. How to do it depends on the version of EF you are using, because you must tell the EF to use some SQL native functions. And you don't gain very much by doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the member declaration in the anonymous type i think. I can do this:

```
var holidays = context.tblHolidayCalendars.Where(x => !x.isDelete)
                          .Select(x => new 
                                 { 
                                      Id = x.recordId,
                                      DateString = x.date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
                                 });

Console.WriteLine(holidays.First().Id);
Console.WriteLine(holidays.First().DateString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your latest comment, this issue arises from the usage of the extension method ToString on date.

Any property initialised with an expression must have a name specified; if a property is being used to initialise, the name is inferred from that property. In your case, `date.ToString()` is an expression so the name must be provided.

```
.Select(x => new
{
    x.recordId,
    x.date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"),
});
```

becomes,

```
.Select(x => new
{
    x.recordId,
    date = x.date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"),
});
```